# Automation code coverage when application code is in different repo

Tags: code-coverage, istanbul

Requirement : I want to get the coverage of application code being tested by the automation code.

Problem : Automation and application code are in separate repos

Tech Stack : WebdriverIO, Typescript. Using Istanbul as code coverage tool

1. How do you derive code coverage reports for integration and e2e
   tests that exercise code in multiple repos/services?
2. How do you orchestrate the code coverage tool when the test code is in a
   separate repo than the application code?

Comment: you could make a shell script to clone the test repo into the application code repo, run the tests, and then delete that repo